# What is the standard practice way to return "totals" from other tables with SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple table with users, a simple table with a row for each time a user completes work, and a third table with a row for each time a user is assessed. I want to build a view that shows me the total from each table. There are a myriad of ways to achieve this, but what is the most optimal, CPU-least intensive and standard practice way to do this?

I usually do this with `OUTER APPLY` but in this particular scenario, I feel a CTE would probably be more efficient or even a sub-query. I can't seem to get this right by using a `JOIN` and then `COUNT/SUM` and `GROUP BY` as it tends to duplicate or produce incorrect figures.

Here's how I'm currently doing this (minimal replicable example) but it feels unnecessarily slow:

```sql
SELECT u.[userID],
       u.[Name],
       u.[Team],
       w.[Work],
       q.[Quality],
       FORMAT(q.[Total] / w.[Total], 'P') as [%]
  FROM [Users] AS u
 OUTER APPLY
       (
           SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Total]
             FROM [Work] as w
            WHERE 1=1
                  AND w.[UserID] = u.[userID]
                  AND w.[Date] < DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 6 + 7) - 7)
       ) as [Work]
 OUTER APPLY
       (
           SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Total]
             FROM [Quality] as q
            WHERE 1=1
                  AND q.[UserID] = u.[userID]
                  AND q.[Date] < DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 6 + 7) - 7)
                  AND q.[Result] = 'FAIL'
       ) as [Quality]
```

Comment: Your method is fine.  However, there might be more efficient ways to write this particular query using window functions.  But that would require sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you are trying to do.  You could probably further simplify this "minimal example" as well by removing a bunch of columns.

Comment: Optimal query depends on available indexes, whether you can create them and your data distribution. The way the question is asked now, it is too vague.

Comment: The _actual execution plan_ is often the place to start with performance issues. Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a way to include an execution plan in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have better performance using CTE.

you can do it like this:

```sql
WITH WorkSums AS
(
    SELECT      w.[UserID],
                COUNT(*)    AS [Total]
    FROM        [Work]      AS w
    WHERE       w.[Date] < DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 6 + 7) - 7)
    GROUP BY    w.[UserID]
),

QualitySums AS
(
    SELECT      q.[UserID],
                COUNT(*)    AS [Total]
    FROM        [Quality]   AS q
    WHERE       q.[Date] < DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 6 + 7) - 7)
                q.[Result] = 'FAIL'
    GROUP BY    q.[UserID]
)

SELECT  u.[userID],
        u.[Name],
        u.[Team],
        FORMAT(qs.[Total] / ws.[Total], 'P') as [%]

FROM        [Users]     AS  u
LEFT JOIN   WorkSums    AS  ws  ON  ws.[UserID] = u.[UserID]
LEFT JOIN   QualitySums AS  qs  ON  qs.[UserID] = u.[UserID]
```

Comment: Final `SELECT` should have left joins, though, because original query had `OUTER APPLY`.

Comment: Thanks @YairMaron - although am I right in thinking (whilst not applicable for this example, so thank you!) that the difference between a CTE and `APPLY` in this case, is that you can't join onto the data with a CTE? So if the date was required to be filtered via a field in the `[Users]` table, you'd need to perform an `APPLY` or `JOIN`?

Comment: when you're using OUTER APPLY you can bind the sub-query whichever way you like to the main query, so usually it is more flexible than JOIN which requires ON, however you pay in performance. So joining CTE tables (which acts like undefined views) may have sometimes better performance.